# grep only area in between two strings

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I'm having this problem where in trying to grep something on an html page (specifically a user name) I try to retrieve the string by saying:

```
egrep -o dir\=\"[ltr]*\"\>.*(\<\/span|\<\/a)
```

By this I am trying to say: "get anything after dir=("ltr or rlt")> and before the first `</a>` or `</span>` closing tag.

so for example:

```
dir="ltr">myusername</span>
```

or

```
dir="rtl">myusername</a>
```

There are however multiple span tags on one line, and it is not stopping after the first one, which results in data that I don't want.

Is there a way to modify my current regex to stop after the first one?  And why does it even continue reading?

Thanks

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221277/bash-grep-between-two-lines-with-specified-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the `.*` non-greedy by adding a `?` to it.

```
egrep -o dir\=\"[ltr]*\"\>.*?(\<\/span|\<\/a)
```

A better solution is this (in raw regex, you will need to escape it):

```
dir="[ltr]{3}"[^>]*?>(.*?)(</span>|</a>)
```

Capture group 1 ($1) will contain what is between it, and capture group 2 ($2) will contain if its a span or a link termination.

See it in action:
http://regexr.com?32b8k

Answer (score 0):

I would use `GNU sed` to do this:

```
sed -r 's/(dir="ltr"|dir="rtl")>([^<]+)(<\/span>|<\/a>).*/\2/' file.txt
```

You can make the regex a bit more clever and easier to read with some simplification:

```
sed -r 's/dir="(ltr|rtl)">([^<]+)<\/(span|a)>.*/\2/' file.txt
```