# Bash, grep between two lines with specified string

Tags: regex, bash, grep

Example:

```
a43
test1
abc
cvb
bnm
test2
kfo
```

I need all lines between test1 and test2. Normal grep does not work in this case. Do you have any propositions?

Comment: This answer might also be applicable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48022994/2026975

Answer (score 75, accepted):

> Print from `test1` to `test2`  (Trigger lines included)

```
awk '/test1/{f=1} /test2/{f=0;print} f'
awk '/test1/{f=1} f; /test2/{f=0}' 
awk '/test1/,/test2/'
```

```
test1
abc
cvb
bnm
test2
```

---

> Prints data between `test1` to `test2` (Trigger lines excluded)

```
awk '/test1/{f=1;next} /test2/{f=0} f' 
awk '/test2/{f=0} f; /test1/{f=1}'
```

```
abc
cvb
bnm
```

Comment: Hello sir , do you know how can use your same script in shell language

Comment: If my input is in a string, how would I use this to process that string?

Comment: @LennartRolland See my post here about how to get data inn to awk from variables. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-to-use-shell-variables-in-awk-script/19075707#19075707

Comment: How would you modify this to include one trigger line, but not the other? i.e., include `test1`, but not `test2`

Comment: @Eddie This should print all from "test1" to end of file  `awk '/test1/{f=1} f'`  if you like to not print the trigger, then swap it around.   `awk 'f; /test1/{f=1}'`

Comment: What if I don't need a precise match? For example, I need to match lines from one word till the beginning of the square bracket `[` which also contains a word, that is not yet known.

Comment: @t7e Post a new question with an example data.

Comment: Would be better if you could explain what the commands here mean

Answer (score 59):

You could use `sed`:

```
sed -n '/test1/,/test2/p' filename
```

In order to exclude the lines containing `test1` and `test2`, say:

```
sed -n '/test1/,/test2/{/test1/b;/test2/b;p}' filename
```

Comment: Or, if you are OK with shell expansion in your sed string, you can do `start="test1"; end="test2"; sed -n "/$start/,/$end/{/$start/b;/$end/b;p}" filename`. That way you only have to type each search pattern once.

Comment: To exclude the lines it can be shortened to just `sed -n '/test1/,/test2/{//b;p}'`

Comment: What does `//b` mean? I just know `b` means branch, but I don't know about `//`

Comment: Is it possible to print few lines before 'test1' string and few lines after 'test2' string? What modifications are required?

Comment: How to print filename also along with the expected output? Can this take multiple file inputs? e.g. sed -n '/test1/,/test2/p' filename1 filename2

Comment: Would be better with semantics explained

Comment: Does not work on macos :(

Answer (score 15):

If you can only use grep:

```
grep -A100000 test1 file.txt | grep -B100000 test2 > new.txt
```

`grep -A` and then a number gets the lines after the matching string, and `grep -B` gets the lines before the matching string. The number, 100000 in this case, has to be large enough to include all lines before and after.

If you don't want to include test1 and test2, then you can remove them afterwards by `grep -v`, which prints everything except the matching line(s):

```
egrep -v "test1|test2" new.txt > newer.txt
```

or everything in one line:

```
grep -A100000 test1 file.txt | grep -B100000 test2 | egrep -v "test1|test2" > new.txt
```

Comment: I didn't know about `egrep`, interesting, thanks. Details here. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17949/what-is-the-difference-between-grep-egrep-and-fgrep

Comment: just want to point out the obvious that this might fail if test1/test2 pairs occurs more than once in the input.

Comment: @LennartRolland in which case, it takes the **first** occurrence of test1, and the **first** occurrence of test2 after that, which happened to be exactly what I wanted. :)

Answer (score 8):

Yep, normal grep won't do this. But grep with `-P` parameter will do this job.

```
$ grep -ozP '(?s)test1\n\K.*?(?=\ntest2)' file
abc
cvb
bnm
```

`\K` discards the previously matched characters from printing at the final and the positive lookahead `(?=\ntest2)` asserts that the match must be followed by a `\n` newline character and then `test2` string.

Comment: Which grep flavor is this? I'm on mac os and there is no -P. What meaning does -P have in the grep context above? It would also help to explain -oz if they are part of the solution. In mac os grep -o is --only-matching and -z is --decompress. The former might be relevant but the latter doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: P represents perl regex. ie, we can use perl regex on grep. Unfortunately grep on Mac won't support this option.

Answer (score 1):

To make it more deterministic and not having to worry about size of file, use the wc -l and cut the output.

grep -A`wc -l test.txt|cut -d" " -f1` test1 test.txt | grep -B`wc -l test.txt|cut -d" " -f1` test2

To make it easier to read, assign it to a variable first.

fsize=`wc -l test.txt|cut -d" " -f1`; grep -A$fsize test1 test.txt | grep -B$fsize test2

Answer (score 0):

The following script wraps up this process. More details [in this similar StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35322020/26510)

#### get_text.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function show_help()
{
  ME=$(basename "$0")
  IT=$(cat <<EOF

  $ME: extracts lines in a file between two tags

  usage: FILENAME {TAG_PREFIX|START_TAG} {END_TAG}

  examples:
    $ME 1.txt AA     => extracts lines in file 1.txt between AA_START and AA_END
    $ME 1.txt AA BB  => extracts lines in file 1.txt between AA and BB
EOF
)
  echo "$IT"
  echo
  exit
}

if [ "$1" == "help" ]
then
  show_help
fi
if [ -z "$2" ]
then
  show_help
fi

function doMain()
{
  FILENAME=$1
  if [ ! -f $FILENAME ]; then
      echo "File not found: $FILENAME"
      exit;
  fi

  if [ -z "$3" ]
  then
    START_TAG=$2_START
    END_TAG=$2_END
  else
    START_TAG=$2
    END_TAG=$3
  fi

  CMD="cat $FILENAME | awk '/$START_TAG/{f=1;next} /$END_TAG/{f=0} f'"
  eval $CMD
}

doMain "$@"
```

Comment: I love this answer, small and strong!

Comment: It just encouraged me to trust the `awk` answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this too. Lets say you this file `test.txt` with content:

```
a43
test1
abc
cvb
bnm
test2
kfo
```

You can do

`cat test.txt | grep -A10 test1 | grep -B10 test2`

where `-A<n>` is to get you `n` lines after your match in the file and `-B<n>` is to give you `n` lines before the match. You just have to make sure that `n > number of expected lines between test1 and test2`. Or you can give it large enough to reach EOF.

Result:

```
test1
abc
cvb
bnm
test2
```

Comment: this  is  cool  if you know number  of lines,  but is  not so  in real  world  when  you need  to  get  all lines between  two  markers.  For  example  a  list of files  are  packed  into  a  tar,  but  you  do  not  know which ones  and  you want full list.  Then  your solution will not  work.  Jotne's solution will work  perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by PratPor above:

```
cat test.txt | grep -A10 test1 | grep -B10 test2
```

is cool.. but if you don't know the file length:

```
cat test.txt | grep -A1000 test1 | grep -B1000 test2
```

Not deterministic, but not too bad. Anyone have better (more deterministic)?