# How to extract a string from between two patterns in bash

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Im begining with bash and I want to find my ip in a .txt file analyzing it.
This is an example of part of the file:
"Direc. inet:192.******  Difus.:"

The path I think on is searching all the text between "inet:" and " ". My biggest approach until now is getting the entire line with "grep inet:" but I can't figure out how to get just the ip not the entire line with the ip.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're on Linux, you can take advantage of GNU `grep`'s `-o` and `-P` options:

```
grep -oP '(?<= inet:)[^ ]+' file.txt
```

Example:

```
$ grep -oP '(?<= inet:)[^ ]+' <<<'Direc. inet:192.****** Difus.:'
192.******
```

- `-o` tells `grep` to only output the matching part(s) of each line.
- `-P` activates support for PCREs (Perl-compatible regular expressions), which support look-behind assertions such as `(?<= inet:)`, which allow a sub-expression (`inet:`, in this case) to *participate* in matching, without being *captured* (returned) as part of the matched string.
- `[^ ]+` then simply captures everything after `inet:` up to the first space char. (character set `[^ ]` matches any char. that is not (`^`) a space, and `+` matches this set 1 or more times).

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -ne 'print $1, "\n" if /inet:([^ ]+)/'
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line;
- `[^ ]` matches a character that isn't a space
- `+` means the character must be present one or more times
- `(...)` creates a capture group, the first capture group is referenced as `$1`

Answer (score 0):

Try combination of `awk` and `grep`. Below solution may help [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242469/how-to-use-sed-grep-to-extract-text-between-two-words) .
[Lin 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221277/bash-grep-between-two-lines-with-specified-string)

Comment: Please avoid [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info).