# Filtering lines of a text file

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I have a situation similar to [Bash, grep between two lines with specified string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221277/bash-grep-between-two-lines-with-specified-string). I have a text file with output in the following format:

```
HEADER A
lines of output
----------------
HEADER B
lines of output
----------------
...rinse and repeat...
```

I want to match all the blocks with the same header. `grep` does not seem sufficient for this task. And I am only vaguely familiar with `awk` and `sed`. Just enough to realize they might be the most appropriate tools here. So how do I match a block that is enclosed with matching HEADER and ---------- lines?

My attempt based on the linked question is

```
awk '/HEADER/{f=1} /-/{f=0;print} f' filename.txt
```

However, this still matches some of the lines in the blocks with the second header.

Comment: Maybe you need to expand your input file a bit and advise how the wrong output you get looks like...

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou Just edited to show more clearly the file format.

Comment: Why not `awk '/HEADER A/{f=1}/-------/{f=0;print}f' file.txt` ...?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou That is almost a solution. I just realized that my original `awk` command matched unwanted lines with negative numbers. Your proposal also matches **all** lines with dashes, even those which terminate a block with a header other than the one I am trying to match. This is usable, just not 100% ideal.

Comment: _I want to match all the blocks with the same header_ What does it mean? What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Adjusting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22221307/1222951) to fit the problem, I got:

```
sed -n '/HEADER/,/-/p' filename.txt
```

This is rather brittle (it stops when it finds a hyphen), so something like

```
sed -n '/HEADER/,/^-+$/p' filename.txt
```

to check for a full line of hyphens might be preferable. As far as I can tell (not a `sed` expert), everything between the slashes is just regular regex with the multiline flag `m` enabled.

Comment: My little bit of research showed that the `'x,y'` syntax matches multiple lines from `x` to `y`, which can be specified with regexes. As far as I can tell, each regex only matches individual lines, though.

Comment: I already encountered the brittleness of your first solution. The blocks with the second header contains negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

For a file like this:

```
$ cat file1
HEADER A
lines of output1.1
----------------
HEADER B
lines of output2.1
----------------
HEADER A
lines of output1.2
----------------
HEADER B
lines of output2.2
----------------
HEADER A
lines of output1.3
----------------
HEADER B
lines of output2.3
----------------
```

Something like this gives all HEADER A lines :

```
$ awk '/HEADER A/{f=1} /-------/ && f==1{f=0;print} f' file1
HEADER A
lines of output1.1
----------------
HEADER A
lines of output1.2
----------------
HEADER A
lines of output1.3
----------------
```

You just need to make one AND condition (&&) at the terminating line

If this is not what you need, i'm afraid you should retype your question to be a bit even more clear.

Comment: Could you explain, what is the function of the `f` at the end of your command? If `f` is 1, then print the record, is this corect?

Comment: @FloHe in `awk` world, the last `f` is an awk shortcut to say`if f==1 then print` (or in awk code `f==1{print $0}`). More precisely a single f is a condition check that is equivalent to `if f is not zero or f is not unset then print the line`. More over, in awk we can ommit the `{action}` part in the awk syntax which is `condition{action}` . Ommiting the action , the default action is performed = print the line = `{print $0}`

Comment: Good answer, thanks

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Did this worked as expected?