# How to Start and Stop printing lines with Specific Text in Linux/Unix Terminal

Tags: linux, shell, unix, terminal

Print file on terminal Starting and Ending in a line with specific Text

For Example: file.txt

```
2019/10/17 23:01:02 -W- Blah Blah Blah.....
2019/10/17 23:01:02 -I- Blah Blah Blah.....
2019/10/17 23:01:02 -I- Blah Blah Blah.....
2019/10/17 23:01:02 -I- Start
2019/10/17 23:01:02 -I- ======================
2019/10/17 23:05:02 -I- Summary Details
2019/10/17 23:10:02 -I- End
2019/10/17 23:10:02 -I- Blah Blah Blah.....
2019/10/17 23:10:02 -I- Blah Blah Blah.....
2019/10/17 23:10:02 -I- Blah Blah Blah.....
```

I tried to display the lines with grep cmd, but I am unable to the required output.

Expected Result:
Command to get the results based on system date

```
> some command in grep (or) awk (or) sed with system date for current date

2019/10/17 23:01:02 -I- Start
2019/10/17 23:01:02 -I- ======================
2019/10/17 23:05:02 -I- Summary Details
2019/10/17 23:10:02 -I- End
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+how+to+filter+lines+between+patterns https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988756/how-to-select-lines-between-two-marker-patterns-which-may-occur-multiple-times-w

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash, grep between two lines with specified string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221277/bash-grep-between-two-lines-with-specified-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way in `awk` is just keep a flag and set `n = 1` when `"Start"` is encountered in *field 4*. Checking `n == 1` gives you a test to print each line while `n` is `1`. When `"End"` is reached, simply print that line and exit, e.g.

```
awk '$4 == "End" {print; exit} $4 == "Start" {n = 1} n == 1' file
```

(**note:** the operation associated with the rule `n == 1` is simply the default operation of `print`. It is equivalent to writing `n == 1 {print}`)

**Example Use/Output**

Using your data file in `file`, you would get:

```
$ awk '$4 == "End" {print; exit} $4 == "Start" {n = 1} n == 1' file
2019/10/17 23:01:02 -I- Start
2019/10/17 23:01:02 -I- ======================
2019/10/17 23:05:02 -I- Summary Details
2019/10/17 23:10:02 -I- End
```

It can also be written as:

```
awk '$4 == "Start" {n = 1} n == 1; $4 == "End" {exit}' file
```

**Edit - Todays Date Only**

If you want to match today's date only, you simply need to pass the date in the format you need as a variable to `awk` from the shell using the `-v` option, e.g.

```
awk -v date="$(date +%Y/%m/%d)" '
    $1 == date { 
        if($4 == "Start") n = 1
        if(n == 1) {print}
        if($4 == "End") exit
    }
' file
```

**Example Input**

```
$ cat file
2019/10/17 23:01:02 -W- Blah Blah Blah.....
2019/10/17 23:01:02 -I- Blah Blah Blah.....
2019/10/17 23:01:02 -I- Blah Blah Blah.....
2019/10/17 23:01:02 -I- Start
2019/10/17 23:01:02 -I- ======================
2019/10/17 23:05:02 -I- Summary Details
2019/10/17 23:10:02 -I- End
2019/10/17 23:10:02 -I- Blah Blah Blah.....
2019/10/17 23:10:02 -I- Blah Blah Blah.....
2019/10/17 23:10:02 -I- Blah Blah Blah.....
2019/10/20 23:01:02 -W- Blah Blah Blah.....
2019/10/20 23:01:02 -I- Blah Blah Blah.....
2019/10/20 23:01:02 -I- Blah Blah Blah.....
2019/10/20 23:01:02 -I- Start
2019/10/20 23:01:02 -I- ======================
2019/10/20 23:05:02 -I- Summary Details
2019/10/20 23:10:02 -I- End
2019/10/20 23:10:02 -I- Blah Blah Blah.....
2019/10/20 23:10:02 -I- Blah Blah Blah.....
2019/10/20 23:10:02 -I- Blah Blah Blah.....
```

**Example Use/Output (for 2019/10/20)**

```
$ awk -v date="$(date +%Y/%m/%d)" '
>     $1 == date {
>         if($4 == "Start") n = 1
>         if(n == 1) {print}
>         if($4 == "End") exit
>     }
> ' file
2019/10/20 23:01:02 -I- Start
2019/10/20 23:01:02 -I- ======================
2019/10/20 23:05:02 -I- Summary Details
2019/10/20 23:10:02 -I- End
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. @David C.Rankin. How to edit awk to include current system date? I want my command to pick up current date from column 1

Comment: Isn't that what was done? you have the date `2019/10/17` in the output -- or are you saying forget the date in the input file and just replace it by the current system date?

Comment: Yes everyday date will change, I need the command to pick up the current date automatically and show up the lines only for the current day. For example if I run the command today it should show up the start and end portion of lines for 2019/10/20, if I run it tomorrow it should show up the start and end lines for 2019/10/21

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` script. With explanation:
It will solve for printing partial terminating sections as well.

#### script.awk

```
BEGIN {FS=" -I- "}  # Field separator is " -I- ", therefore idicative field data is in fiedl $2
$2 ~ "^Start"{onSection = 1} # if indicative field start with "Start", mark section flag ON
onSection{print} # print output only if marked section flag ON
$2 ~"^End"{onSection = 0} # if indicative field ends with "End", mark section flag OFF
```

#### running

```
awk -f script.awk file.txt
```

or one liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=" -I- "}$2~"^Start"{f=1}f{print}$2~"^End"{f=0}' file.txt
```

#### output

```
2019/10/17 23:01:02 -I- Start
2019/10/17 23:01:02 -I- ======================
2019/10/17 23:05:02 -I- Summary Details
2019/10/17 23:10:02 -I- End
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/Start$/,/End$/p' input
```

To filter on today's date:

```
sed -n "\@$(date +%Y/%m/%d)@"'{ /Start$/,/End$/p; }' input
```