# Extract text from multiline content using sed

Tags: xml, bash, shell, sed

How to extract the content between CDATA in the example below using `sed` (or another easy method) ?

The tricky thing is that the pattern must be evaluated on multiple lines, and also one part of the line must be kept in extracted result... so I expected some powerful tools like `sed` or `awk` to be able extract content of a file using a capturing regular expression .. without success !

Example of content:

```xml
<XmlBox className="com.example.ConfigData">
<xmlString><![CDATA[<ConfigData>
<myField>Here we go:

Yup.
</myField>
</ConfigData>]]></xmlString>
</XmlBox>

<XmlBox className="com.example.ServiceDefinition">
<xmlString><![CDATA[<ServiceDefinition>
<name>Tricky?</name>
</ServiceDefinition>]]></xmlString>
</XmlBox>
```

Expected result:

```xml
<ConfigData>
<myField>Here we go:

Yup.
</myField>
</ConfigData>

<ServiceDefinition>
<name>Tricky?</name>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

The related regular expression to capture it would be:

`(?s)<XmlBox className=".+?">\s+<xmlString><!\[CDATA\[(.+?)\]\]></xmlString>\s+</XmlBox>`

But HOW to automate this in a simple bash command ??
I thought it was so easy, isn't it ?

Comment: I would highly suggest using a program that is meant to deal with xml to parse xml. Like `xlmlint` or `xml_grep`.

Comment: yes, but I don't want to rely on a "valid" xml parser, here it is just a matter of extracting a captured group, or doing substring between markers... no big deal, right ? btw, this would be useful for other needs, but thanks for the hint.

Comment: No big deal. Like [parsing html with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2221001) it's a fine idea.

Comment: 99.999% of my use cases should work here... so I don't care :)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, this is a terrible idea.  But, if you want to shoot yourself in the foot:

```
perl -000 -pe 's/<XmlBox className=".*">\s+<xmlString><\!\[CDATA\[([^]]*)\]\]><\/xmlString>\s*<\/XmlBox>/$1/' input
```

Comment: Note that we could also use the exact same regexp as provided, by using `perl -00 -pE 's|CAPTURING_REGEXP|$1|' input.xml`. `-E` for full featured regexp and `|` for sed-like separator to not conflict with regexp. Great. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Sed is awkward with multiline data. As others have mentioned, it's not a great tool for this job, but if that's what you really want, use tr to remove the newlines and then add them back in, e.g.

```
cat myfile | tr '\n' '\007' |sed 's/fromwhatever/towhatever/'
```

Then use tr to put the newlines back in. In the example above, octal 7 is a bell (which presumably doesn't occur in your data -- you can use any character that's not already present.

Answer (score 0):

Another pretty simple solution:

```sh
grep -ozP '(?s)<XmlBox className=".+?">\s+<xmlString><!\[CDATA\[\K.+?(?=\]\]></xmlString>\s+</XmlBox>)' data.xml
```

- `\K` discards the previously matched characters from printing at the final
- the positive lookahead `(?=matchAfter)` asserts that the match must be followed by *matchAfter* expression.

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/28060342/1034782

Answer (score 0):

**Best solution found is using Python.**

Write a (very) few lines of code in `replace.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, re

# config
file = sys.argv[1]
find = sys.argv[2]
repl = sys.argv[3]

# run
with open (file, "r") as myfile:
     s=myfile.read()
print re.sub(find, repl, s)
```

Call it as below:

```sh
./replace.py input.xml 'CAPTURING_REGEXP' '\1' > output.xml
./replace.py input.xml '(?s)<XmlBox className=".+?">\s+<xmlString><!\[CDATA\[(.+?)\]\]></xmlString>\s+</XmlBox>' '\1' > output.xml
```

It does exactly what it is supposed to do (no drawback) and is surprisingly fast (10s to process a 750MB file).

Thanks to [@kpie answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27335357/1034782) for the hint.

Comment: Doesn't work if the pattern spans a line unless you use re.DOTALL